# Monotonicity of $(f \circ f)$ and $(f \circ f \circ f)$ for strictly monotonic $f$

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

> Let $f$ be a strictly monotonic function.
>
> What can we say about $(f \circ f)$ and $(f \circ f \circ f)$,
>
> 1. when $f$ is strictly increasing,
> 2. when $f$ is strictly decreasing?
>
> Please provide a proof.

Comment: Please provide your work.

Comment: I don't know how to proceed on this. Please help.

Comment: you should be able to prove it just by using the definition of strictly increasing function.

Comment: Well,  I assume there are asking are $f(f(x))$ and $f(f(f(x)))$ strictly monotonous?  Are they strictly in/decreasing or not if $f$ is?  The answer and proof should be really easy and obvious.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @fleablood how is this obvious? Please help

Comment: Well, to be fair @dankmemer , to prove *what*?  The question doesn't actually ask *anything* is it isn't nesc. clear *what* to prove.

Comment: What can you say about fof(x) & fofof(x) if f is strictly increasing. Provide proof

Comment: How is it obvious??  What is the definition of monotonic/increasing/decreasing.  If $x$ is increasing what is the behavior of $f(x)$? And if $f(x)$ is behaving in that way, how is $f(f(x))$ behaving?  That should *really* be obvious.

Comment: Just apply definition.  If $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$ then $f(f(x))\dots$

Comment: If f is strictly increasing, I get how fof is increasing too, but if f is strictly decreasing, what about fof & fofof?

Comment: Here is an intermediate excercise for you:  If $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, is $f(f(x))$ also strictly increasing?  State the definition of "strictly increasing" and use the definition to prove it or explain how it might not be true.... That really is *all* the explanation I think anyone should need.  There is nothing more to say.

Comment: The way I read the problem, we will finally have a bonus task: Can *all* strictly increasing functions $g$ be written as $f\circ f=g$ with strinctly increasing $f$? With strictly decreasing $f$? Similar for the cube part ...

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I was reading it as differentiation in a hurry. Sorry. Thank you all

Comment: That's your job.  If $f(x)$ is increasing, then $f(f(x))$ is strictly increasing.  Why?  I want *you* to explain why?  I want you to look at the definition of "strictly increasing",  see what it means and show that if it applies to $f$ it *must* also apply to $f\circ f$.  Start by stating the definition.

Answer (score 0):

If f is strictly increasing then whenever a< b, then f(a)< f(b).  Then, since f(a)< f(b), fof(a)= f(f(a))< f(f(b))= fof(b).

Answer (score 0):

*This is more a long comment than a definite answer:*

You cannot conclude in general if you do not impose constraints on the domain of definition of $f$, for instance take $f(x)=\pm(x^2-1)$ whether you want an increasing or decreasing function on $\mathbb R^+$.

$f(x)=x^2-1$ is $\nearrow$ on $\mathbb R^+$ but $f\circ f$ presents two monotonicities and $f\circ f\circ f$ has three on that same interval. (i.e. has resp. 2 and 3 intervals where it is strictly monotonic).

Nevertheless, there is a case when you can conclude easily, this is when $f$ is strictly monotonic and continuous on whole $\mathbb R$ because now you get a bijective mapping from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and no matter how many times you compose the function, $f^{\circ[n]}$ will stay a continuous bijection and thus will be strictly monotonic.

The case when $f$ is not necessarily continuous but still monotonic on whole $\mathbb R$ can be dealt with the numerous hints that were provided to you in the comment section.